# Cannot delete file used by some other process

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, file-io, ioexception

I am displaying some image in my wpf app using following code:

```
 <Image Source="{Binding Path=TemplateImagePath, Mode=TwoWay}"  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"  Width="400" Height="200"/>
```

and setting it's binding property inside code behind's constructor by navigating through some directory, below is the code:

```
DirectoryInfo Dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:/Template");
            if (Dir.Exists)
            {
                if (Dir.GetFiles().Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (FileInfo item in Dir.GetFiles())
                    {
                        TemplateImagePath = item.FullName;
                    }
                }
            }
```

but if user upload some other image then I need to delete this old image which is I am doing in the following way and setting image binding to null:

```
DirectoryInfo Dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:/Template");
                if (Dir.Exists)
                {
                    if (Dir.GetFiles().Count() > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (FileInfo item in Dir.GetFiles())
                        {
                            TemplateImagePath= null;
                            File.Delete(item.FullName);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

But Iam getting exception that Cannot delete file used by some other process.
How can I delete it?

Comment: Did you try not using a TwoWay Binding? Another solution that could work is to not directly setting a path, but creating a BitmapImage from the path and binding to that bitmap image.

Comment: how to do that. I am newbie in WPF.any code example

Comment: Sorry, no time, use Google please.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to be able to delete the image while it is displayed in an ImageControl, you have to create a new [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms619218.aspx) or [BitmapFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms619213.aspx) object that has [BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcacheoption.aspx) set. The bitmap will then be loaded from file immediately and the file is not locked afterwards.

Change your property from `string TemplateImagePath` to `ImageSource TemplateImage` and bind like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding TemplateImage}"/>
```

The set the `TemplateImage` property like this:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
image.UriSource = new Uri(item.FullName);
image.EndInit();
TemplateImage = image;
```

or this:

```
TemplateImage = BitmapFrame.Create(
    new Uri(item.FullName),
    BitmapCreateOptions.None,
    BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
```

---

If you want to keep binding to your `TemplateImagePath` property you may instead use a [binding converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) that converts the string to an ImageSource as shown above.

Comment: Also I need to add 'System.GC.Collect();                                System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();'                                 before deleting that file that is before this line: File.Delete(item.FullName)

Comment: Spent ages on this, but adding 'GC.Collect();' and 'GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();' before deleting solved my issue. Thanks @SST

Comment: @Jon You may also want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13262548/1136211. While triggering the GC might work, the "correct" (i.e. documented) solution would be to set the StreamSource instead of the UriSource property.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks, I'll take a look

Comment: How you do this with video ?

Answer (score 0):

According to Clemens suggestion, here is the binding converter to have a good code-reuse:

```
namespace Controls
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(String), typeof(ImageSource))]
    public class StringToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (!(value is string valueString))
            {
                return null;
            }
            try
            {
                ImageSource image = BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(valueString), BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
                return image;
            }
            catch { return null; }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And there is a string for binding, for example

```
public string MyImageString { get; set; } = @"C:\test.jpg"
```

And in the UI the converter is used, in my case from the Library named "Controls"

```
<Window x:Class="MainFrame"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Controls;assembly=Controls">
    <Window.Resources>
        <controls:StringToImageSourceConverter x:Key="StringToImageSourceConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="{Binding MyImageString, Converter={StaticResource StringToImageSourceConverter}}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```