# How to display images in listview?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I am trying to get images from folder and store them into a class name 'Project'.

Then I want to display them in listview.

So I could show list of images in each project class with project name at above.

This is 'Project' class.

```
public class Project : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private int id { get; set; }
        private string name { get; set; }


        private bool isChecked;



        public int ProjectId
        {
            get { return id; }
            set
            {
                id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string ProjectName
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return isChecked; }
            set
            {
                isChecked = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public List<string> projectImages { get; set; }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }
```

This is function which add images into list.

```
 private void menu_Open_Project(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            
            

            var imageList = GetImageFromDirectory.GetImageFiles(some directory path goes here);

            if (projects.Count > 0)
            {
                var lastIndexNumber = projects.Last().ProjectId + 1;

                projects.Add(new Project() { ProjectId = lastIndexNumber, ProjectName = "Project " + lastIndexNumber.ToString(), projectImages = imageList });
             }
          }
```

This is the xaml with list view

```
 <ListView Name="projectListView" Background="LightGray">

                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}">
                            
                            <GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

                                            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2, 2, 2, 2">
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProjectName}" Background="Gray"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </Border>
                                            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2, 0, 2, 2">
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Image/>

                                                </Grid>
                                            </Border>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            

                        </GridView>

                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Comment: Which image file in the list of image file paths you want to shown in `Image`?

Comment: @emoacht, thnank your for the comment! The images in the 'List<string> projectImage' in 'Project' class. Images' path will be retrieved and saved into that list when program starts. There are total 3 image address in that 'List<string> projectImage'.

Comment: So you want to show one of them or all of them?

Comment: @emoacht All of them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ItemsControl` and its derived controls to show multiple images.

In addition, setting the path of image file directly to `Image.Source` is not ideal because it will lock that image file. Instead, it is recommendable to use a converter which converts file path to `BitmapImage`. We can use `StringToImageConverter` in [Clemens's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12867281/3137337) for this purpose.

So, assuming width of each `Image` is 100, such `ItemsControl` will be as follows;

```
<!-- Somewhere in xaml such as Window.Resources -->
<local:StringToImageConverter x:Key="StringToImageConverterKey"/>

<!-- Inside DataTemplate of GridViewColumn.CellTemplate -->
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding projectImages}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Width="100" Source="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource StringToImageConverterKey}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```