# How to dispose Image Source in WPF

Tags: c#, .net

In WinForms, I can dispose of an image like this

```
pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
```

I know that `Picturebox.Image` control in WinForms is `Image.Source` in WPF. But there is no `dispose()` method in `Image.Source`.

I also see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908383/how-to-release-image-from-image-source-in-wpf).

But why is it so complicated compared to WinForms?

Is there any equivalent method in WPF?

Comment: See here: [WPF Image control not disposing source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49144817/7444103)

Comment: Why do you want to dispose Image.Source directly? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: please refer to this link <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788855/binding-an-image-in-wpf-mvvm> It can be done with MVVM. WPF is using a different approach for desktop development. Most of WinForms development method didn't apply to the WPF!

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/26532667/34092 help?